# How to use Joins in IIF() function and how to use select statement inside nested IIF () in MSAccess query?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, case, iif-function

I came to know that one can't use case expressions in Ms-access queries. Instead one has to use IIF() function. I have a MS SQL query which needed to convert to Ms-access query for one of the pre-existing old Legacy application. I know the general syntax for IIF() function; however, I have the complex case expression with two tables joining with each other. Can any of you help me out here?

```
CASE 
    WHEN ISNULL(tblDetail.ProductDiscPct,0)<>0 THEN 'MFG'
        WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM ORDER_Shipment os 
            JOIN [ORDER_Items] oi 
            ON os.OrderId = oi.orderid 
            AND oi.MaterialId = tblDetail.MaterialID
            AND ISNULL(oi.ItemStatusId,0)=0
            AND oi.OrderItemTypeId = 300 
            AND [tblDetail].[Quantity] = [oi].[Qty]
            WHERE CAST(tblInvoice.ARInvID AS varchar) = os.InvNumber
            ) 
        THEN 'SPECIAL'
    ELSE ''
END AS LnNote
```

This is the MS SQL query which I need to convert to MS-access query that I attempted as following but didn't give me any result instead it took away my drop-down options of the control-source for the fields in the access report.

`IIf(IsNull(qryDetail.ProductDiscountPct <> 0, "MFG", "" )) AS LnNote`

This is only first line of the case statement I have been struggling to work. `qryDetail` is just a sub-query in my main query.

Comment: Can you not nest `IIF`?

Comment: @shahkalpesh: Yes, I could but I am having hard time on nesting IFFs and I am just a beginner for access.

Answer (score 0):

`IIF` returns a `BOOLEAN` for `ms-access` so check if the `ISNULL` is true or not, and if it is then set it to 0 or itself. Then check that value compared to 0 and return MFG or "".

`IIF(IIF(IsNull(qryDetail.ProductDiscountPct),0,qryDetail.ProductDiscountPct) <> 0,"MFG","")  AS LnNote`

Comment: Thanks @scsimon I am going to try this. But I still have some nested part. i.e. `WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM ORDER_Shipment os 
            JOIN [ORDER_Items] oi 
            ON os.OrderId = oi.orderid 
            AND oi.MaterialId = tblDetail.MaterialID
            AND ISNULL(oi.ItemStatusId,0)=0
            AND oi.OrderItemTypeId = 300 
            AND [tblDetail].[Quantity] = [oi].[Qty]
            WHERE CAST(tblInvoice.ARInvID AS varchar) = os.InvNumber
            ) `

Comment: @toofaced then you would replace the "" with your subquery

Comment: OK. I thought that was my last option as initially I started working on it by creating sub-query which gave me error highlighting all after  `JOIN' statement

Answer (score 0):

```
IIF(Nz(tblDetail.ProductDiscPct,0) <> 0, "MFG", 
    IIF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ORDER_Shipment os 
    JOIN [ORDER_Items] oi 
    ON os.OrderId = oi.orderid 
    AND oi.MaterialId = tblDetail.MaterialID
    AND ISNULL(oi.ItemStatusId,0)=0
    AND oi.OrderItemTypeId = 300 
    AND [tblDetail].[Quantity] = [oi].[Qty]
    WHERE CAST(tblInvoice.ARInvID AS varchar) = os.InvNumber) > 0, "SPECIAL", "")
) AS LnNote
```

This is a crude translation of what you have in SQL.
Moreover, it uses `COUNT(*)` instead of `EXISTS`. I am assuming it won't be too many records in that area so as to make the query slow.

`Nz` is similar to `ISNULL`.

Does this help?

Comment: I think MS-access didn't like select statement inside IIF statement. It throws me an error message `Syntax error. in query expression 'IIF(NX(qry.....)' . Tried different ways a) removed aliased. b)give nice square parenthesis in every alias. Both of them didn't work. Also, I think access doesn't understand the word `JOIN` so I used `INNER JOIN`

Comment: It is `Nz`, not `Nx`. What is the place where you are seeing the syntax error?

Comment: sorry that was a typo I had used 'Nz' and it highlights whole select statement as a syntax error. I had tried creating a 'sub-query' for that select part too but for the sub-query it is also giving me error.

Comment: Post your entire query in the original question so as to understand the syntax error.